Language-specific code blocks versus default code blocks
I've sometimes noticed in the Suggested Edits queue, and even in some code I have written here, that this suggestions is often pushed forward, where it appears the code block already used includes the ```r operator instead of the typical code chunk on CV:

Is there a reason this is often suggested?

Without highlighting:

And when ```r is added:

Thus it is intended for syntax highlighting as has been explained in this Meta post (emphasis mine):

On most coding-related sites, Highlight.js is used to add color to the code, but only if the language can be uniquely determined given the tags of the question (certain tags have language hints specified in their data), or if manual hints have been provided on the same line after the opening code fence, or in HTML comments ...


Thanks! I never noticed that until now, but that makes it much more clear as to why people choose to do it this way instead.

Better late than never :-)

TBH I find the code highlighting with colour a little more distracting than it is helpful. I understand my perceptions are not everyone's but it's not unambiguously an improvement, since it depends on perception and not all neuro-s are typical. I guess it's just another thing I have to force myself to put up with now.

@ShawnHemelstrand by the way, this is actually much more general than R. You can write "python" instead of "r" when the code snippet contains Python code, for example. You can find the full list of supported languages here (see the "aliases" column).
